# How to stop imported python script from running , but only runs when called in code

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import, python-module

When i import one of my python scripts and run my current script , it seems to be running and displaying the output of the imported script which is really unusual behaviour. I have just imported this in my script but not really called any of its functions in my main code. How can i avoid from this behaviour happening ?

If i pass the -d flag with my main script it will run the usual code in my main script only

If i pass the -t flag with my main script , it will run the code from the imported python script only

main.py

```
import os
import argparse
import functions as funcs
import generate_json as gen_json
from test_compare_filesets import tester as imptd_tester


def get_json_location():
    path = os.getcwd() + '/Testdata'
    return path


def main():

 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store_true", required=True)
 parser.add_argument("-t", "--execute-test", action="store_true", required=False)
 args = parser.parse_args()
 date = args.export_date
 testt = args.execute_test

 yml_directory = os.listdir('yaml/')
 yml_directory.remove('export_config.yaml')



 with open('dates/' + date + '.json', 'w') as start:
  start.close()

 for yml in yml_directory :
   print("Running export for " + yml)
   yml_file = os.path.join('yaml/' + yml)

   json_path = get_json_location()
   yml = funcs.read_config(yml_file)
   data_folder = date
   gen_json.generate_data_report(json_path , yml , data_folder)


if __name__ == '__main__':


   main()
```

test_files.py

```
import generate_report as generate_reportt


def compare_filesets(file_names, previous_data, current_data):
    for item in file_names:
        print(item + generate_reportt.compare(previous_data.get(item), current_data.get(item)) + "\n")


def test_filesets():

 '''
Test for scenario 1
'''

dict_1 = generate_reportt.read_file_into_dict("dates/2018-01-01.json")
dict_2 = generate_reportt.read_file_into_dict("dates/2018-01-02.json")
print(" Test 1 ")
compare_filesets(file_names=['a.json', 'b.json', 'c.json'],
                 previous_data=dict_1,
                 current_data=dict_2
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why using the statement:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

is very important. You will want to add this to the script you're importing, and put all of your code that is being called within a `main()` function in that script. The variable `__name__` of a script changes depending on whether the script is imported or not. If you're not importing the script and running it, then that script's `__name__` variable will be `"__main__"`. However, if it is imported, the `__name__` variable turns into the script's filename, and therefore everything in `main()` function of that script will not be run.

For more information: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if this worked for you :)